# How to add Google sign in and leaderboard?

Tags: android, google-play-services

So I have made a small Android game(private) and I want to put Google sign in and Leader Board so I can play with my friends.

I have searched on youtube how to create a Google sign in but I didn't find any step by step videos.
Also, when I tried configuring app on https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating#next_steps
with com.example and sha1 I got an error:

> "Something went wrong when creating your project. Please try again
>   later."

Any ideas?
I have never tried implementing Google services again so I am a total newbie.
I have added `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'`

Answer (score 4):

I've been trying the same thing, and didn't find any up to date tutorial. I give you the steps I've figured out so far:

Create a Google Play Console account (costs 25 USD)

Create a project there and follow through all the steps in your projects' "Game Services", like "Linked Apps", "Achievements", "Leaderboard"....

Under achievements scroll down to "Get resources" and copy the code to res/values/games-ids.xml in your Android Studio project.

This tutorial: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/get-started-with-google-play-games-services--cms-27755 is good until that point, but the code to call the Google Api is deprecated.

Follow the official guide to set up a Google sign-in instead: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in

The leaderboard: https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/leaderboards

And the achievements: https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/achievements

You do not need to create neither a .xml nor a .java file for the leaderboard and achievements, the code samples in the tutorials above will call the standard dialog for this automatically.

Hope I could help a little bit :)